# 404 not found laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel , I am getting 404 not found error when returning view to salary report from my controller. The below mentioned is my function which returns my simple view to salary report.

```
    public function getSalaryReport()
        {
            return view('Company.salaryReport');
        }
```

the routes.php file ahs route to company controller.

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth.company'], function () {
        Route::get('company/notice-board/create', 'CompanyController@getNoticeBoardCreate');
        Route::get('company/notice-board/{id}/edit', 'CompanyController@getNoticeBoardEdit');
        Route::get('company/designation/{id}/edit', 'CompanyController@getDesignationEdit');
        Route::get('company/all-user/{id}/force', 'CompanyController@getForce');
        Route::post('company/all-user/{id}/force', 'CompanyController@postForce');
        Route::controller('company', 'CompanyController')
```

this is my view which i am trying to display from my controller.

```
@extends('Company.CompanyLayout')
@section('content')
<div>
    <ul class="breadcrumb">
        <li>
            <a href="{!! URL::to('company') !!}">Home</a> <span class="divider">/</span>
        </li>
        <li>
             <a href='{!! URL::to("company/report-summery") !!}'>Summery Report</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
@endsection
```

where i am going wrong and what should be done to make my view visible. Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: company/salaryreport in ur view

Comment: are you sure the `Company` folder is starting with capital letter ?

Comment: What URL are they visiting?

Comment: no brother it is giving me same error.

Comment: james it is visiting the same url like report-summery

Comment: yes i am sure company folder is starting with capital letter mr.Elwan

Comment: Remove middleware group from route and give a try

Comment: Mr.Muthu it gave me the same error.

Comment: Whats the version of your laravel and check Route::controller will work or not

Comment: what's your laravel version?

Comment: can you give more example for make us clearer..

we need your entire routes file, controller, and your view tree

Answer (score 1):

`Route::controller` is depricated in the latest versions of Laravel, try not to use it anymore.

You can use `Route::resource` or create a specific route for your salary report like this:

```
Route::get('company/salary-report', 'CompanyController@getSalaryReport');
```

Also make sure that you have `resources\views\Company\salaryReport.blade.php` as your view.

Comment: thank you man you made my day.. it works when i use salary-report but not when i use report-salary  can you tell me why

Comment: change route path from Route::get('company/`salary-report`', 'CompanyController@getSalaryReport'); to Route::get('company/`report-salary`', 'CompanyController@getSalaryReport');

Comment: no man when i use this it gives me 404 not found can it be issue of htaccess

Comment: Usually htaccess has nothing to do with this. how is your url look like?

Answer (score 1):

`404 not found` is an error because you don't have any routes for the given url. And I didn't find any routes in your example for the function `getSalaryReport()`

if you want to call this method, at least add this to your routes:

`Route::get('company/report-summery', 'CompanyController@getSalaryReport');`